# calculate the difference between two time durations php

Tags: php, time, duration

I Have two-time durations

1. 5 hours and 55 minutes.
2. 6 hours.

expecting the answer +5.00 or -5.00 for the difference between.

what are the best options to resolve the matter?

Comment: Show us your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$time1 = '05:55';
$t1=strtotime($time1);

$end=strtotime('06:00'); 

$Min = floor((($end- $t1)/60));    

echo   $Min.' Min ';

?>
```

Comment: Cool .. Simple and save my day. :)